# Convert JSON to SQL and put record to table which has foreign keys in Apache Nifi

Tags: apache-nifi

I'm having a **TrackingEvent** table in PostgreSQL, which has foreign keys, for e.g: **customer_id**. I have transformed the raw JSON data to proper JSON data (JSON fields match SQL columns)

```
// tracking event data
{
    "event_id":"abcd1234",
    "customer":"m2-123456"
}
```

I also have 2 SQL tables:

1. Customer

| PK | id | integer |
| --- | --- | --- |
|  | name | varchar(255) |

2. TrackingEvent

| PK | id | integer |
| --- | --- | --- |
| FK | customer_id | integer |
|  | type | varchar(255) |

`FOREIGN KEY (customer_id) REFERENCES Customer(id)`

When putting data to SQL, I want to convert **customer** value to **customer_id** with strategy: firstly check **Customer** table with `name==customer`, decide to create new customer, then put record to **TrackingEvent** with returned **customer_id**.

So, I want to know: is there any template or proper way to achieve this? Or any specific keyword which I can look up.

Thank you very much.

#### Update 1

The data stored in SQL will look like:

```
// Customer Table
1,"m2-123456"

// TrackingEvent Table
1,1,"click"
2,1,"view"
3,1,"buy"
```

Comment: Why do you need to generate any is when you have one? `m2-123456`

Comment: Well, it's obviously unique. But it's an ID, not a SQL key. I have updated the question to describe what the data in SQL looks like (update 1).

Comment: I would insert data as is and use it without relational. It'll be faster. If you still want to split data to relational tables - use SQL to transform data from raw_events to relational tables.

Comment: Could you provide more detail about `SQL transform data to relational tables`?. I think this might be the solution I need.